# Tensor product of (general?) groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am starting to learn about tensor products of abelian groups.

Why is the tensor product defined for **abelian** groups? In which part of the construction the commutativity of the groups is needed?

Comment: There is no (important) tensor product for groups. But tensor products of  modules over commutative rings exists and are important. An Abelian group is a $\mathbb Z$-module.

Comment: check this http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_groups

Comment: @janmarqz Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: If I want the tensor product on two groups $G$ and $H$, couldn't I generate the free group by the elements of $G \times H$ and then quotient by the corresponding relations? When does this construction fail?

Comment: @MattSamuel: I am new on the subject, i am thinking

Comment: @zxv: but what do you mean with a tensor product between two groups? The universal property does not exist for this, I think.

Comment: @Lehs: you should check the link I gave

Comment: @janmarqz, yes I have seen it. I might be wrong, but I think it's a "kind of" type of tensor product, rather than an object with a universal property.

Comment: I was wrong. The tensor product of general groups really satisfies the universal property, due to the link in the answer of @3 1 3. Which was interesting for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a version of the tensor product for nonabelian groups, but this notion is much more specialized. See http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~loday/PAPERS/87BrownLoday%28vanKampen%29.pdf, section 2. In the construction at some point you do a mod out, which you cannot do in general if you do take the free group instead of the free abelian group. (You see a free group on some set is nonabelian unless the set has cardinality $>1$, so you need to have a normal subgroup to form the mod out, and the standard way to get over this issue is to take the normal closure. This is implicit in the paper, where they use a presentation.)

see also http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonabtens.html

Comment: Could you be more specific about which mod out wouldn't work?

Comment: @zxv: in the tensor product for abelian groups you consider $F(A\times B)/N$ where $F(A\times B)$ is the free abelian group on $A\times B$ and $N$ the subgroup generated by the defining relations. For the nonabelian tensor product you must take $N$ to be the normal subgroup generated by the relations (a presentation). But this is a natural thing to do

Comment: If it is natural, what's the problem then? If I quotient the free group by the normal subgroup generated by those relations, don't I get what I want?

Comment: @zxv: sorry, I didn't see your response. No there is not a problem, it is very natural generalization, you certainly get what you want. I just pointed out what one has to change.

Answer (score 5):

@Laters: Just to add to the answer of laters, the following should explain the idea of the nonabelian tensor product. More details are in the Brown-Loday paper linked in that answer.

Let $M,N$ be normal subgroups of the group $P$. Consider the commutator map

$$c=[\, ,\, ]: M \times N \to P, (m.n) \mapsto mnm^{-1}n^{-1}.  $$
Then $c$ is **not** bimultiplicative but it is a *biderivation* in the sense that there are formulae for $[mm',n], [m,nn'] $,  which I leave you to work out, and which involve the conjugation $^n m= nmn^{-1}$. So we form the universal construction for biderivations, i.e.  a biderivation $\kappa: M \times N \to M \otimes N$ which is universal for biderivations; it is constructed from the free group on $M \times N$, by factoring out the biderivation rules. One has to do some fiddling to prove some key properties; the main one is  to use the biderivation rules to interpret $mm' \otimes nn'$ in two ways, ending up with the nice formula 
$$[m,m'] \otimes [n,n']= [m \otimes n,m' \otimes n'].   $$

Since $\kappa$ is a morphism it has a kernel.  The main result of the BL paper implies that this kernel is isomorphic to $\pi_3(X)$ where $X$ is given by the pushout of spaces

$$\begin{matrix}K(P,1) & \to & K(P/N,1) \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
K(P/M,1) & \to & X \end {matrix} $$
while $\pi_2(X)  \cong (M \cap N)/ [M.N]$. A useful special case is when $M=N=P$, when $X\simeq SK(P,1) $.

January 10: To answer the original question, if you seek for a universal object $M \otimes' N$  for **bimultiplicative** maps, then fiddling with expressing $mm' \otimes nn'$ in two ways leads one to the conclusion that $M \otimes
' N$ is abelian, and is the usual tensor product of the abelianisations of $M,N$. This argument can be found in some classics on group theory.

Comment: A reference for the last paragraph? A rapid look in google book gives *Non-Abelian Homological Algebra and Its Applications*, Hvedri Inassaridze, chapter VI, but that part is not available for free and this seems a quite advanced book.

Answer (score -3):

The tensor product in defined for $R$-modules, with $R$ unit ring, and the abelian groups are $\Bbb{Z}$-modules.